# Trying to open SQL Server 2016 with no splash screen and with multiple .sql files

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to open multiple queries in one instance of MS SQL Server 2016 and I need to do it without bringing up the splash screen each time my program runs. I was directed here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162825.aspx
where it says by passing the right combo of command line arguments you can open Ssms without the splash screen and also with multiple .sql files at the same time, but it doesn't give me an example of how to do this. Can anyone please give me some help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I seriously want to question why you want to open SMSS from an app like this. I would recommend either executing the script from your app direct, or make a small console app to do this for you, or use SQLCMD to execute from the commandline. I'd be nervous about letting my users anywhere near SMSS, and if they are proficient enough to be in there, they wont mind the splash screen

Answer (score 0):

For the command SSMS, it looks like this is the syntax:

```
Ssms "C:\folder\nameoffile.sql"  "C:\folder\nameoffile2.sql" -nosplash
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't adequately explain my need. I'm opening Ssms via a c# application, so ultimately I'm not touching it. I need the program to open Ssms itself with no splash screen and at the same time have it open multiple queries that have already been stored off.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not condone, nor recommend anyone else use SMSS in this way from a Production Released Application. You would be far better off executing SQL from inside your application where you have better control over the connection itself as well as feedback to the user and error handling :)

From C# you can execute any command prompt commands using System.Diagnostics.Process class. In other environments you might refer to this as "Shell Execute"

```
string path2SMSS = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe";
string arguments = @"""C:\folder\nameoffile.sql""  ""C:\folder\nameoffile2.sql"" -nosplash";
// Add connection info to the arguments - assuming you have read the response from SMSS /?
arguments += " -S (local) -D master -E";
System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName: path2SMSS, arguments: @"""C:\folder\nameoffile.sql""  ""C:\folder\nameoffile2.sql"" -nosplash");
// If you want to block the calling thread until the process has completed wait for exit.
p.WaitForExit();
```